# How to install Seurat package in R studio on a remote server

Tags: rstudio, seurat

I am trying to install Seurat in Rstudio in my remote Rstudio server. However, after installing and typing the command line library(Seurat), I saw the message that "package or namespace load failed for ‘Seurat’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):....". Please advise on how I can solve this problem.

Thanks

**I go to terminal to access to our remoter server, and try to use install.packages('Seurat'). Then I receive the following message:**

"Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://packagemanager.posit.co/cran/**linux**/jammy/latest/src/contrib/Seurat_4.3.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'binary/octet-stream' length 2175064 bytes (2.1 MB)"

downloaded 2.1 MB

- installing *binary* package ‘Seurat’ ...
- DONE (Seurat)

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/Rtmp19gQMr/downloaded_packages’

**Then I type library(Seurat) in my laptop terminal, and found the message below:**

The legacy packages maptools, rgdal, and rgeos, underpinning the sp package,
which was just loaded, will retire in October 2023.
Please refer to R-spatial evolution reports for details, especially
https://r-spatial.org/r/2023/05/15/evolution4.html.
It may be desirable to make the sf package available;
package maintainers should consider adding sf to Suggests:.
The sp package is now running under evolution status 2
(status 2 uses the sf package in place of rgdal)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Seurat’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/igraph/libs/igraph.so':
libglpk.so.40: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

**Note, I have no problem installing Seurat in Rstudio in my own laptop though.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is with the igraph package. You should try re-installing it. This thread on github might help https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/452

As an alternative, on the remote server have you tried to use conda to create a new environment for your R packages and then installing Seurat via conda with the following?

```
conda install -c bioconda r-seurat
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out on my own.  I have to redefine the libPaths() to the folder that I need to install the package. Thanks for your suggestion though.